# See when an executable opens and closes

Tags: objective-c, callback, executable, exit, launch

How can I get a callback within my application when an executable (such as pbs, cp, etc) launches and then exits? This would need to work only knowing the path to the executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move the original executable aside, and replace it with a wrapper that runs the original, reporting when it runs and exits.

You could look at the `accton` and `lastcomm` commands, which record the start and exit of every process on the system.

You could look into using dtrace, which can definitely do what you're asking but it's rather complicated to use.  You'd probably have to do a fair amount of learning to do this.  I don't know much about writing dtrace scripts, but I'd probably start with [execsnoop](http://www.brendangregg.com/dtrace.html) as my model.

Comment: dtrace looks like what I need. I'll look into it